# Redux Form needs to display my filtered values in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Using Redux Form I'm able to retrieve the values which I enter in username. I'm able to filter out the corresponding values, but I need to display my filtered values in the browser.

```
console.log("pilot.name--->", pilot.name);
```

Can you tell me how to do it? I provided my code snippet and sandbox below. My related code is in showResults.js: https://codesandbox.io/s/xl1r14w854.

```js
var pilots = [
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Wedge Antilles",
      faction: "Rebels"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Ciena Ree",
      faction: "Empire"
    },
    {
      id: 40,
      name: "Iden Versio",
      faction: "Empire"
    },
    {
      id: 66,
      name: "Thane Kyrell",
      faction: "Rebels"
    }
  ];

  var rebels = pilots.filter(function(pilot) {
    // return pilot.faction === "Rebels";
    // return pilot.faction === values.username;

    if (pilot.faction === values.username) {
      console.log("pilot.name--->", pilot.name);
    }
  });
```

Comment: If I use my username as 'Empire' it works fine. What is the expected functionality?

Comment: @ShivamGupta hey thansk for your reply...filtered values I need to show it in the browser as a list `console.log("pilot.name--->", pilot.name);`

Comment: do you mean you want to show it to the user if the pilot.faction validation is True?

Comment: when this condition is true ` if (pilot.faction === values.username) {` then i need to show the pilot.name to the users

Comment: Since you already have window.alert. Use that inside the if condition, like 
window.alert(pilot.name)

Comment: @ShivamGupta hey I need to show in li tags in the browser, not using alerts :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a separate reducer for this. Imagine that you call that reducer `PilotsReducer` where you have your list of pilots in the state. That reducer is "listening" to a specific action like `loginSubmitted` that you trigger when you get the response from the server.

The payload of that action will be the username that you use to do the filter. In the reducer you can then do the filter and set a state property (e.g. `rebels`) to the result of the filter. Your component can then be attached to redux to pick the `rebels` property and it will re-render when that property changes.

This is a typical flow of react/redux, it is not specific to your example

On a side note you can improve it by using `reselect` so you would keep the entire list of pilots in the state, and filter them in a `selector` by passing the current username to it. Please check the docs and tutorials of redux and reselect to have a clear view of the entire workflow.